# Defining a type in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was at an exam today where i got this question: find an expression or function definition in Haskell that has this particular type `:: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]`

How would i do that?

or is this even possible without a parameter as input to the function?

Comment: Your title is misleading; you *have* a type; you need to find a *value* that has that type.

Comment: Note that the exact wording of the question might be important here. A common question is to find any term (any expression) that has a given type. Another question is to find any term such that its _inferred type_ is the given type. The latter question is usually more challenging. If the wording is exactly what you posted, though, it looks like your exam question is of the former kind.

Answer (score 5):

If you're allowed to access the internet, you could [ask Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(Num%20a%2C%20Enum%20a)%20%3D%3E%20%5Ba%5D), but otherwise, here's how I'd approach it:

Consider the building blocks you're given. You can use all the functions or values defined by `Num` and `Enum`, but that's it. The value you're asked to suggest isn't a function (it takes no input), so you'll have to conjure values out of those two type classes, if you want any values at all.

The simplest expression possible I think is to just return the empty list:

```
foo = []
```

This, in itself has the type `[a]`, but if you annotated it, you could artificially constrain it:

```
foo :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
foo = []
```

This is possible, but may be considered cheating. If so, proceed to actually look at what building blocks are provided by `Num` and `Enum`.

The richest source of implementations seems to be `Num`, since it defines `fromInteger`. With that single function, you can implement infinitely many expressions of the type `Num a => [a]`, e.g.

```
[fromInteger 1]
[fromInteger 2]
[fromInteger 3]
```

I'm sure you get the picture... From there, you may consider if you can somehow use a capability from `Enum`.

How about `enumFromThen`?

```
enumFromThen (fromInteger 1) (fromInteger 9)
enumFromThen (fromInteger 2) (fromInteger 8)
enumFromThen (fromInteger 3) (fromInteger 7)
```

and so on...

Now, it turns out that number literals are already treated as `Num` values, so you can actually simplify the above to

```
enumFromThen 1 9
```

and so on.

If I understand the question correctly, you're only being asked to give an example. If so, those should suffice, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

One example of a function with this type would be:

```hs
thing :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
thing = [9001..]
```

Number literals in Haskell are polymorphic and integer number types have an `Enum` instance.

You can decide the actual concrete type (specialize) on the call site e.g.,

```hs
intThing :: [Int]
intThing = thing
```

or

```hs
integerThing :: [Integer]
integerThing = thing
```